# ROS Answers SE migration: roswarn in cpp

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm used to rospy.loginfo/rospy.logwarn/rospy.logerr but I can not find how to use them in cpp. Can somebody tell me it please?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12114/roswarn-in-cpp/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you looking for this?
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-11-27**:
I think so! Thanks!